# How to align subplot with specified size?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have a lot of different plots, wich sizes must be strongly specified. One plot per one file. The problem is that when size too large I have some free spaces in subplot from the left, which I want to crop. I can't use `subplots_adjust` because plots with small sizes will be croped too. Also I can't use `tight` option when I call `savefig`. So, how can I align all my plots to the left side with fixed indent in all my files?

```
import sys, os
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

path = sys.path[0]
sizes = [(12,3,), (4,3,)]
x =  range(20)


for i, size in enumerate(sizes):
    fig = plt.figure(figsize = size, dpi = 80, facecolor='white', edgecolor=None, linewidth=0.0, frameon=True, subplotpars=None)
    ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
    ax.plot(x)
    plt.ylabel ('Some label')

    fig.savefig(os.path.join(path, 'size_'+str(i)+'.png'), dpi=80, facecolor=fig.get_facecolor(), edgecolor=None, papertype=None, format='png' ,transparent=False)
```

[image: large sized image][image: small sized image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can just use [tight_layout()](http://matplotlib.org/users/tight_layout_guide.html):

```
import sys, os
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

path = sys.path[0]
sizes = [(12,3,), (4,3,)]
x =  range(20)


for i, size in enumerate(sizes):
    fig = plt.figure(figsize = size, dpi = 80, facecolor='white', edgecolor=None,linewidth=0.0, frameon=True, subplotpars=None)
    ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
    ax.plot(x)
    plt.ylabel ('Some label')

    plt.tight_layout()

    fig.savefig(os.path.join(path, 'size_'+str(i)+'.png'), dpi=80,facecolor=fig.get_facecolor(), edgecolor=None, papertype=None, format='png',transparent=False)
```

Also you can use something like

```
fig.subplots_adjust(right=0.9, left=0.1, top=0.9, bottom=0.1, wspace=0.2)
```

instead of `plt.tight_layout()`. If you want.

Please, tell me if that's not what you need.

Comment: @user1426156, then can you please mark my answer as accepted? :) It will be +15 reputation for me and +2 reputation for you. Thank you!